# VBA Run-time error on copying to csv

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am getting a run-time error on a copy method.

> "Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Copy' of object 'Range' failed"

```
Sub SaveCSV()

    Worksheets("export").Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\export.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Windows("exportData.xlsm").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:60"), "SaveCSV"

End Sub
```

but when I debug it shows that Worksheets("export").Copy

Comment: On what line is the error message?

Comment: `TimeValue("00:00:60")` is a runtime error 13: type mismatch. Use `TimeValue("00:01:00")` or `timeserial(0,0,60)`.

Comment: the error show on line 2 `Worksheets("export").Copy`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error with the information you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

There was a February 2015 security update to Excel 2010 that causes this problem when copying whole worksheets. Removing the update can fix the problem.

This is the link: [MS15-012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956081)

On that page you will see that there is another update that may fix this problem. This is the link to that update: [KB2956084](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956084)

So you can try the 'fix' or uninstall the offending security update.

Comment: There is actually an update to "Hopefully" fix the problem (Can't check as i don't have office 2010). Just as described in the link also :)